# How Can I Download Files from FTP using C#?

Tags: c#, ftp

I am trying to download files from FTP.but Server return an Error 550(File not found,no access)
below my code,

```
FtpWebRequest reqFTP;

try
{

    FileStream outputStream = new FileStream("d:/test/" +
                            "\\" +a , FileMode.Create,FileAccess.Write,FileShare.Read);

    reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("ftp://example.com/" + " /" + a));

    reqFTP.KeepAlive = false;
    reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
    reqFTP.UseBinary = true;
    reqFTP.Proxy = null;
    reqFTP.UsePassive = false;
    reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("aaaa", "bbbb@1234");


    FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)reqFTP.GetResponse();
    // ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, errors) => true;

    Stream ftpStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    long cl = response.ContentLength;
    int bufferSize = 2048;
    int readCount;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

    readCount = ftpStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
    while (readCount > 0)
    {
        outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, readCount);
        readCount = ftpStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
    }

    ftpStream.Close();
    outputStream.Close();
    response.Close();
}
catch (WebException ex)
{
    //MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    String status = ((FtpWebResponse)ex.Response).StatusDescription;
    MessageBox.Show(status);
}
```

Files are can Display in List.while reading no Problem,while downloading it's throws an error-550,in my ftp i am having .txt,img,.pdf,.rar,.exe file formates.

Comment: Network Credential correct?

Comment: The error 550 is a Permission-Denied-Error-Message. Are you able to download data with the `Credentials` you provided?

Comment: can you please explain what type of credentials i need to give?

Comment: Your slashes around "d:/test/" should be replaced with \. I'd also add a @ to avoid having to escape the backslashes, like @"d:/test/"

Comment: i have changed that slashes,but still i am getting same error

Comment: If you try to acces the ftp file using a browser, does it works?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this article: [Using the C# WebClient class to upload and download FTP files](http://www.dijksterhuis.org/webclient-class-upload-download-ftp-files/)

Basically, it relies on the `WebClient` objet that do all the network stuff.

The article wraps it in a custom class, that works with credential.

The important part of the article is:

```
public byte[] DownloadData(string path)
{
    // Get the object used to communicate with the server.
    WebClient request = new WebClient();

    // Logon to the server using username + password
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Username, Password);
    return request.DownloadData(BuildServerUri(path));
}
```

Just ensure the credentials and path are correct.

Answer (score 0):

I am just set exact path in FTP address,and set buffer size also high value,then its works fine.

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://example.com/file path);
```

buffer size,

```
 byte[] buffer = new byte[32 * 1024];
```